# Spotify's Android SDK can't play songs with short duration reliably

Tags: android, spotify

### TL;DR

I am trying to playback songs with a duration less than <s>10</s> 40 (extremely hard to tell) seconds using the Spotify Android SDK. I am using a button to start playback. When doing so there is no sound most of the time. Spamming the button causes to play sound occasionally (happens hardly ever). `PlayerEvent`'s `kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged` & `kSpPlaybackEventAudioFlush` are missing if there is no sound.

### Description

I am using [Spotify's Android SDK](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk) ([Docs](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/player/)). I am trying to play songs using `playUri(...)`. Certain songs won't render any sound at all after calling `playUri(...)` even tho the `Player.OperationCallback`'s `onSuccess` is reached. In another more complex testing environment, I found out that the `Player.AudioDeliveredCallback` is not even getting called when this behavior appears. The one thing the non-working tracks have in common is that they are short (duration of fewer than <s>10</s> 40 (extremely hard to tell)  seconds).
I am using the Android SDK version `spotify-player-24-noconnect-2.20b` and debug on devices running Android OS version `4.4.2` & `7.0`.

I also listed this as an issue in the Spotify Android SDK which can be found [here](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/404).

### Steps to Reproduce

I am using [this](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) as a starting point. I removed all of the authentication related code due to I am simply grabbing the OAuth token by myself using the Web API. As well I ignored the Android package name & SHA1 fingerprint pair that should be provided within the Spotify app due to it seems that this is not even getting checked by the service. The player is getting initialized properly which I can tell because there are songs that play without any problems. Therefore `ConnectionStateCallback`'s `onLoggedIn()` is getting called after a short period of time. A debug log message confirms the success of the login procedure. After logged in successfully `playUri(...)` is ready to be used by calling it with a Spotify URI. The following implementations of `View.OnClickListener`'s `onClick(...)` methods are used for five different `Button`'s that utilize `playUri(...)` with a working (Button 5) and some non-working (Button 1-4) Spotify URIs.

```java
public void onButtonClickedPlaySong1(View view) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing short song");
  mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:5vN4teJoROMQoadL4IzejG", 0, 0);
}

public void onButtonClickedPlaySong2(View view) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing short song");
  mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:46O6QtxuzX3iZn9hMXoeqo", 0, 0);
}

public void onButtonClickedPlaySong3(View view) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing short song");
  mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:770fJdqw14GUyCe2SMEgvP", 0, 0);
}

public void onButtonClickedPlaySong4(View view) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing short song");
  mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:4JjsoAKOZZCZuC0kiYwkTL", 0, 0);
}

public void onButtonClickedPlaySong5(View view) {
  Log.d("MainActivity", "Playing long song");
  mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:3CCCpjbs3uW018OkSguRFk", 0, 0);
}
```

#### Actual behaviour

Buttons 1, 2, 3 and 4 should start playback of a short song.
Button 5 should start playback of a long song.

- Pressing one of the buttons 1, 2, 3 or 4 results in no sound playback.
- Pressing one of the buttons 1, 2, 3 or 4 multiple times rarely results in sound playback.
- Pressing button 5 results in sound playback all the time.

#### Expected behavior

- Pressing one of the buttons 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 shall result in sound playback all the time.

### Logs

The following logs mainly show `Player.NotificationCallback`'s `onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent)` calls.

Pressing button 5:

```
02-24 13:19:15.500 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playing long song
02-24 13:19:15.516 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyPlay
02-24 13:19:15.574 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:19:15.692 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:19:15.692 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:19:15.692 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyContextChanged
02-24 13:19:15.791 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackChanged
02-24 13:19:15.791 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackEventAudioFlush
```

Pressing button 1, 2, 3 or 4:

```
02-24 13:20:04.286 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playing short song
02-24 13:20:04.307 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyPlay
02-24 13:20:04.357 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:20:04.463 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:20:04.463 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:20:04.463 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyContextChanged
```

Pressing button 1, 2, 3 or 4 after it was pressed before:

```
02-24 13:20:06.020 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playing short song
02-24 13:20:06.035 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyPlay
02-24 13:20:06.088 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:20:06.179 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
02-24 13:20:06.179 5766-5766/<YOUR_PACKAGE> D/MainActivity: Playback event received: kSpPlaybackNotifyMetadataChanged
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found a fix for the problem. `playUri(...)`'s last parameter is an integer which is called "positionInMs" in the docs. When setting it to `1` instead of `0` I don't have any  problems at all no matter of the duration of the song to be played.

Technically this seems like the song is getting cut by 1 ms which makes it a pretty dirty fix I think. But practically it isn't noticeable at all and that's why I am cool with it.